# AWS CodeBuild, No artifact files specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, composer-php, aws-codebuild

AWS CodeBuild run successfully but does not move the build to S3. It should pull down my code from Github, run some commands, then push a ZIP of all files to S3.

**My [buildspec.yml](https://github.com/justin-cook/j-api/blob/master/buildspec.yml) in github:**

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:      
      - echo Pre-build started on `date`
      - cp envs/.env.test .env
      - composer self-update      
      - composer install --no-interaction   
  artifacts:
    files:
      - '**/*'
```

Here are the logs showing **No artifact files specified**:

```
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 Source is located at /tmp/src930293331/src
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 YAML location is /tmp/src930293331/src/buildspec.yml
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 Registering with agent
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 Phases found in YAML: 2
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 ARTIFACTS: 0 commands
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 PRE_BUILD: 4 commands
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE Success: true
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 Phase context status code: Message: 
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 Processing plaintext environment variables
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 Processing build-level environment variables
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 {}
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 Processing builtin environment variables
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 Moving to directory /tmp/src930293331/src
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 Preparing to copy artifacts
[Container] 2017/04/18 16:33:59 No artifact files specified
```

CodeDeploy settings in the console:

[image]

What have I missed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed the indentation of my artifacts block and it works! It was supposed to have no indentation.

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:      
      - echo *** Pre-Build ***
      - cp envs/.env.test .env      
      - composer install --no-interaction     
artifacts:    
  files:
    - '**/*'
```